# iptables port foward to reverse proxy

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

I'm on an ubuntu vserver and want to port forward clients to a host who's connected via ssh, and has putty configured to remotely port forward the port 1802.

**What I want to accomplish:** I want my vserver to act as a proxy for a given port for an application. I want to be able to connect to my vserver using that port, but be redirected to the reverse proxy (host):

Client A <== x.x.x.x:1802 ==> vserver (port forward) <== reverse proxy / ssh connection ==> Host

**What I already have:** The host already has a remote port forwarding using putty and a ssh connection to my vserver. All I'm missing is the port forwarding, so that Client that connect to the vserver using the specified ports are DNAT'ed to the Host.

**This is what I tried so far:** I tried adding `listen 1802;` in my nginx server config, but that didn't work at all (I think I was missing the `proxy_pass` config). Then I tried using iptables:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i -p udp --dport 1802 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:1802
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i -p tcp --dport 1802 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:1802
iptables-save
```

But I'm unsure about the `--to-destination` parameter. Also, I omitted the `-i` value, so that all interfaces are used for the iptables entry.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need both a PREROUTING and POSTROUTING flag. Additionally, the nginx proxy pass would work for this in TCP stream mode **only**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, adding `GatewayPorts yes` to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` was needed. Restarting ssh didn't suffice, I had to restart the vserver - then it worked. I didn't even need any special iptables entries, cause all ports were on ACCEPT already.

Comment: Restarting sshd doesn't touch existing sessions. Those sessions run with the old config until they logout.